# Validation and scoring using regex in Python 3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, math

ok so I am trying to use regex in python 3 to check a string, if the string has uppercase letters the word scores 5 if it has upper and lower it gets 10 etc. the code beelow sort of works if the word is AAAAAAAA it scores 5 but if it is AAAAAAAAAa it still only scores 5.

```
def word_strength(entered_string):
    wordtrenthscore = 0
    contains_upper ="[A-Z]+"
    validString = re.match(contains_upper, entered_string)
    if validString:
        stringscore += 5


    contains_lower ="[a-z]+"
    validString = re.match(contains_lower, entered_string)
    if validString:
        stringscore += 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
stringscore = +5
```

you want

```
stringscore += 5
```

Also `re.match()` only returns positive value if the `pattern` is at the beginning of string! Change `re.match()` to `re.search()`.

Comment: still does only = 5 when AAAAAAAa is entered

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with "^[A-Z]+$" and "^[a-z]+$" for checking if the whole string is uppercase or downcase?

The "AAAAAAAAAa" string does match your initial regex "[A-Z]+" because it finds 'A' zero or more times (exactly 9), but the a after that doesn't match. If you force the regex until end of line by adding '$' it should work. The same problem would happen with "aAAAAAAAAA" so, the beginning of line '^' is needed too.

So:

```
if re.match("^[A-Z]+$", entered_string):
    stringscore += 5
elif re.match("^[a-z]+$", entered_string):
    stringscore += 5
elif re.match('^[A-Za-z]+$', entered_string):
    stringscore += 10
```

This is unambiguous and does not mix different if-branches.

Comment: Did you read the question? They want to score `10` for string like `AAAa`

Comment: Yes, that's the final 'else' branch. The if-branches are disjunct options.

Comment: This will give a score of `10` for the string `1234`.

Comment: Anchors are superfluous with `re.match`

Comment: Ok. Didn't know, I'm used to working with re.sub(), but I prefer using always anchors for not having to remember when to put them and when not. Uniformity is nicer and I don't mind one or two more chars